# Do I screw down the threshold over my Pergo laminate floors?

Tags: doors, exterior, laminate

I recently replaced 1200 square feet of floors in my home with Pergo Outlast laminate flooring. The floors are done and everything is installed, but I was not sure if I am supposed to screw down the thresholds. I have two exterior doors and on both of them I put the floors under the threshold. Before we had engineered hardwood and the thresholds were screwed into them. I'm just nervous to screw them down because I haven't been able to find anything saying its ok to screw through it. I would hate to see it crack/split when I screw it down. I would think I could drill holes into the floors before screwing into them and that would prevent any issues. Any thoughts on this?

The thresholds are both in place (not moving) with the doors opening and closing multiple times throughout the day for the last month.

Comment: Doesn't Pergo have directions for how to secure these thresholds?

Comment: Are you saying you put the flooring through the thresholds with no gap?  If so, why do you need a threshold at all?

Comment: If they've been in place for the last month without any problems, why worry?

Comment: No, there were no directions about what to do at the threshold.

Comment: The threshold is necessary, we cant just take it out or there would be a huge gap under the door.

Comment: They have been in place, but I think it's only because of the caulking on the exterior side that is holding it in place. I would feel better knowing they are properly secured.